# Draper Labs' Control Moment Gyroscope Spacesuit

Tags: nasa, low-earth-orbit, spacesuits, eva

Back in 2013/2014 Draper Laboratory announced that they were designing and testing a "spacesuit jetpack" that employed control moment gyroscopes (CMG) to allow astronauts to preform EVAs more easily and with more control. Does anybody know what ever happened to this project?

I read that they were testing it in augmented reality. Also, NASA was involved in this process as a sort of curious supervisor?

[Washington Post Article (2013)](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/innovations/wp/2013/06/01/when-you-think-gyroscopes-go-ahead-and-think-the-future-of-spacesuits-and-jet-packs-too/)

Comment: That article sounds like it's more of a IVA garment than an EVA suit. Interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NASA has multiple mechanisms for funding outside organizations to perform NASA-funded research and development. This was one such project, in this case funded through the NASA Innovative Advanced Concepts (NIAC).

Most research and development (R&D) projects do not end in success, and this is not just at NASA. "If we know the answer before we start, it wouldn't be research." Some R&D projects end with a partial success, perhaps pointing the way forward for some future project. Yet other R&D projects (the vast majority) just end.

Organizations that perform R&D should expect most of their R&D projects to not end in glorious success. NASA certainly does not expect most of their R&D projects to end in glorious success. NASA has rather brutal processes for culling both internal and external R&D projects. This particular project exhibits many of the signs of an R&D project that did not end in success. I found a lot of puff pieces published in 2013, and some more that were published in 2015, and then nothing.

The Principal Investigator for this NIAC R&D project worked on two patents related to the technology, ["Exoskeleton suit for adaptive resistance to movement"](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9072941B2/) and ["System and method for assisted extravehicular activity self-return](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20180267534A1/). The first was filed in 2011, before the NIAC grant, and was granted in 2015. The second was filed in 2015 and was abandoned in 2018.